# Deskew rotated image of document

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have OCR dataset of passport IDs. Images could be randomly rotated in the dataset (any angle).

What is the best way to deskew image (this should help for network to detect characters more accurately)?

The easiest way is to train NN for this, but I'm sure, that there should be any classic computer vision approaches for this task.

Comment: Do you mean deskew ?

Comment: yes, fixed question, ty

Comment: Would this be of any help - https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/20/text-skew-correction-opencv-python/ ? Although this works only if the entire text is skewed at a particular angle. Is it possible for you to post some sample images ( or images that might resemble images in your dataset ) to get a better idea of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The passport ID are normalized nowadays.

Try to locate the dark features with the size of a character and cluster them by geometric distance (a good trick is to compute a Minimum Spanning Tree, but this is a little technical).

From the graph of character neighborhood relations, you should be able to identify the dominant orientation and reconstruct the strings.

I know of no ready-made solution that implements this.